# Python - Writing any/all potential errors to a file without defining what part might go wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm looking for some help making sure all errors are saved to a text file but can't seem to find a way to make sure all errors go to file without defining what part the exception handling should be looking at.

I've had a look through http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html but am unable to find anything to suit my needs :/

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this.
Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: If you're trying to do this from inside your Python script, it's just a matter of setting `sys.stderr`, as Joran Beasley's answer shows. If you're trying to do it from outside, it's just a matter of redirecting stderr to a file (e.g., `python myscript.py 2>foo.txt` in bash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open("some_log.txt","wb")
```

I think at least ...

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import sys
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> sys.stderr = s
>>> 5=7
>>> 5/0
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> s.read()
'  File "<stdin>", line 1\nSyntaxError: can\'t assign to literal\nTraceback (mos
t recent call last):\n  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>\nZeroDivisionError:
integer division or modulo by zero\n'
```

Comment: Great answer, but just to make sure the OP doesn't get confused: The one-liner at the top is all you need. The longer `StringIO` thing is a way to test _without_ creating a file. Since you _want_ a file, you don't need that part.

Comment: I seem to have an issue with this, it's not closing the file so I don't get to see the error ever...

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the whole program into a base `Exception`

```
try:
    main()                          # Entry point of your program
except Exception as e:
    str_e = "Error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
    # Print "str_e" to file
    with open("errlog.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(str_e)
```